# Link CSS Not Showing Up

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

My younger sister is having a problem I can't seem to figure out either with her website which is that the links in the sidebar (5 red ones) turn white after being clicked on (visited property). I think this comes from a styling for the navbar, yet when I tried to style these links a different color, using the a:visited property it doesn't appear. In the inspect element there is some tiny warning icon next to the css rule which is crossed out. The website is [here](http://www.engineering.tsaprotectandserve.com).

CSS

```
a
{
color:000000;

}
```

Comment: you need an octothorp preceding the hex number. `a{ color: #000000; }` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a pound `#` next to the color.

```
a
{
color:#000000;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try color:#000000 instead. It looks like you forgot the # for the hex

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
a:active, a { 
color: #000000;
}
```